# Calling macros inside variable in Twig

Tags: twig

Is it possible to call a macro inside a variable using Twig templating?

```
{# in your template #}
{% macro say_hello(name) %}
<p>Oh! Hello {{ name }}!</p>
{% endmacro %}
```

And...

```
// In your php script
$post = "Lorem ipsum... {{ _self.say_hello('name') }} ... plus ultra";
```

And later...

```
{% ...in template... %}
{{ post }}
```

I want to do this to allow users to customize their blog template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't thinks its possible. What you'll end up with is a just raw data from your $post variable something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum... {{ _self.say_hello('name') }} ... plus ultra
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is possible using StringLoader extension.

See this example: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html